# Order by in relations PROPEL

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I have:

```
# config/schema.yml
propel:
  jobeet_category:
    id:           ~
    name:         { type: varchar(255), required: true, index: unique }

  jobeet_job:
    id:           ~
    category_id:  { type: integer, foreignTable: jobeet_category, foreignReference: id, required: true }
    type:         { type: varchar(255) }
    company:      { type: varchar(255), required: true }
```

for example:

```
JobeetCategory:

id | name
1  | first
2  | second

JobeetJob:

id | category_id | name
1  | 1           | bbb
2  | 1           | ccc
3  | 1           | aaa
4  | 2           | zzz
5  | 2           | xxx
```

and I do:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$categories = JobeetCategoryPeer::doSelect($c);
```

and I can:

```
foreach($categories as $category){

  echo $category->getName();
  foreach ($category->getJobeetJobs() as $job){
          echo '-' . $job->getName();
  }
}
```

this show me:

```
 first
 - bbb
 - ccc
 - aaa
 second
 - zzz
 - xxx
```

but I would like have this sorted `ASC by NAME`:

```
 first
 - aaa
 - bbb
 - ccc
 second
 - xxx
 - zzz
```

how can I make it with PROPEL QUERY?

Comment: Which version of propel are you using (and or which version of symfony)?

Comment: this is symfony 1.2. Propel < 1.6

Answer (score 1):

It would have been easier if you had mentioned the version of symfony and propel you're using. But here's something that might work hope it helps.

```
$categories = JobeetCategoryQuery::create()
                            ->addJoin(JobeetJobPeer::CATEGORY_ID, JobeetCategoryPeer::ID)
                            ->addAscendingOrderByColumn(JobeetJobPeer::NAME)
                            ->find();
```

Just incase Query doesn't exist, you could use criteria for the purpose.

```
  $criteria = new Criteria();
  $criteria->addJoin(JobeetJobPeer::CATEGORY_ID, JobeetCategoryPeer::ID)
                        ->addAscendingOrderByColumn(JobeetJobPeer::NAME);
  $categories = JobeetCategoryPeer::doSelect($criteria);
```

Comment: this sort CATEGORY. i want sort JOB

Comment: I don't think `JobeetCategoryQuery` exist in Propel 1.3

Comment: If it doesn't exist. You could use criteria for that purpose.

Comment: Anyway to do this in Propel 2.0? It gives an 'undefined class constant' error on the first appearance of the Model::COLUMN notation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but wanted to give an updated way to do this. You can pass a query object into your getter:

```
foreach($categories as $category){
  echo $category->getName();
  $q = JobeetJobQuery::create()->orderByName();
  foreach ($category->getJobeetJobs($q) as $job){
          echo '-' . $job->getName();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(JobeetJobPeer::CATEGORY_ID, JobeetCategoryPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(JobeetJobPeer::NAME);

$categories = JobeetCategoryPeer::doSelect($c);
```

But `jobeet_job` do not have a column `name`. Are you using a custom getter for `$job->getName()` ?